# Radon–Nikodym derivative of conditional distribution w.r.t Lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Pr)$ is a measure space and $X, Y$ are two continuous random variable defined on it. $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$.

I have known that the Randon-Nikodym derivative of $(\Pr X)^{-1}$ w.r.t Lebesgue measure $\frac{d(\Pr X)^{-1}}{d\mu}$ is $X$'s density function because of the uniqueness of Randon-Nikodym derivative.

What confused me is whether the conditional density function $\frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)}$ is Randon-Nikodym derivative of the distribution of $Y \vert X= x$ and how to illustrate if this statement is right?

I've already made some attempts to handle this problem and find following relating exercise in some textbook:

*Let $(X,Y)$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random variable of density function $p(x,y)$, thus there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
E[X\vert \sigma(Y)] = f(Y),
$$
as $E[X\vert Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.
Please try to show $f(y) = \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}xp(x,y)dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x,y)dx}$.*

I have tried to illustrate above $f(Y)$ satisfies the equation shown as follow:
$$
\int_{A}Xd\Pr = \int_{A} f(Y)d\Pr, \quad \forall A \in \sigma(Y),
$$
which can follow the conclusion that we need because of the uniqueness of conditional expectation, but unfortunately, I encountered some troubles in the process of proving it.

Please help me to above the statement or tell me another way to illustrate  $\frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)}$ is Randon-Nikodym derivative of the distribution of $Y \vert X= x$.

Comment: In the most general definition of conditional expectation this property that you want to prove is the one that defines the conditional expectation in the first place. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош It indeed the definition of conditional expectation in elementary probability, but in measure theory, conditional expectation is always defined as a measurable function w.r.t a sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{F}$. Furthermore, given a random variable $Y$, we can define conditional expectation given $Y = y$ as $E[X\vert Y = y] = f(y)$ as mentioned in description of problem.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош In the other word, I want to check the definition in measure theory is adapted to the definition learned in elementary probability.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of conditional expectation from elementary probability you want to use ?

Comment: @ In my elementary probability textbook, conditional expectation is defined as the integral of conditional density function, that is $E[Y\vert X= x] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}y\frac{p(x, y)}{\int_{\infty}^\infty p(x,y)dy}dy$. It is different from the definition of conditional expectation in measure theory, right?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Thus my question aims to consider the unity of two definition in different course.